# Integrating PayPal with iOS app compile error

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal, compilation

This is my first post on stackoverflow but the site has already helped me loads over the last year or so - so thanks!

Anyway, I am trying to integrate the PayPal payment iOS library into an iPhone app I have been making but when I go to compile the app I get 95 errors the second I try to get an instance of the payment object.

The types of error I am getting is shown below:

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSUserDefaults", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref-to-NSUserDefaults in libPayPalMEP.a(PPUtils.o)


  objc-class-ref-to-NSUserDefaults in libPayPalMEP.a(PPContext.o)
```

"*inflateInit*", referenced from:

```
  -[GZipper DR] in libPayPalMEP.a(GZipper.o)
```

"_xmlNodeListGetString", referenced from:

```
  +[NSString(USAdditions) deserializeNode:] in libPayPalMEP.a(USAdditions.o)


  -[common_PhoneNumberType obfp_deserializeElementsFromNode:] in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)


  -[common_AccountIdentifier obfp_deserializeElementsFromNode:] in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)


  -[common_BaseAddress obfp_deserializeElementsFromNode:] in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)


  -[common_ClientDetailsType obfp_deserializeElementsFromNode:] in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)


  -[common_CurrencyType obfp_deserializeElementsFromNode:] in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)


  -[common_ErrorData obfp_deserializeElementsFromNode:] in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)


  -[common_ResponseEnvelope obfp_deserializeElementsFromNode:] in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)


  -[common_FaultMessage obfp_deserializeElementsFromNode:] in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)


  -[common_RequestEnvelope obfp_deserializeElementsFromNode:] in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)


  -[i_CT obfp_deserializeElementsFromNode:] in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
```

Given there are lots of .o extensions everywhere I am guessing this is a linking error, and not something specific to the paypal library, but I've no idea where to start hunting this issue down. I've searched around quite a lot and nothing has appeared that is even close to the problem, so I am guessing I have done something really stupid when adding the library to my project. I've followed the "how to add.." part of the docs to the letter so really not sure what is up. I've added other library's for other projects in the past but they have been much simpler than this one.

Any help would be much appreciated

Cheers

Simon

ps. library docs found here for those curious [paypal lib docs iOS](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_MPL_Developer_Guide_and_Reference_iPhone.pdf)

**EDIT 1:**

Ok, so thanks to Jim 31 of my errors have gone but I am still left with 64 - here is the as much of the full compile error transcript as S O will let me post, sorry about the length - I've tried digging around it for clues as to where I should be looking but it's beyond my ability at the moment I think so I've not got very far - thanks again for any help!

> Undefined symbols:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSUserDefaults", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSUserDefaults in libPayPalMEP.a(PPUtils.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSUserDefaults in libPayPalMEP.a(PPContext.o)
>     "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIImageView", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalTabView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalTabView.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIFont", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIFont in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPal.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIFont in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalMEPUtility.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIFont in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalViewClass.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIFont in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalGrandTotalView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIFont in libPayPalMEP.a(ReceiverDetailsView.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIButton", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIButton in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPal.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIButton in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalViewClass.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIButton in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalTabView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIButton in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPaymentDetailsView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIButton in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalExpandingView.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSError", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSError in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPal.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSError in libPayPalMEP.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSHTTPURLResponse", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSHTTPURLResponse in libPayPalMEP.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSThread", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSThread in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPageTracking.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSThread in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalProgressIndicator.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSThread in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalCreatePINViewController.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSDateFormatter", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSDateFormatter in libPayPalMEP.a(PPUtils.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSDateFormatter in libPayPalMEP.a(USAdditions.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSDateFormatter in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalViewClass.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSDateFormatter in libPayPalMEP.a(NSDate+ISO8601Unparsing.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSBundle", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSBundle in libPayPalMEP.a(PPUtils.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSBundle in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPageTracking.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSBundle in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileInterrogationReq.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIView", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIView in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMEPRootViewController.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalLoginViewController.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalMEPUtility.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalProgressIndicator in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalProgressIndicator.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalViewClass in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalViewClass.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalViewClass.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPreapprovalCodeViewController.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalCreatePINViewController.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalErrorView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalErrorView.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalAmountView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalAmountView.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalExpandableImageView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalExpandableImageView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalExpandableImageView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPaymentDetailsView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalShoppingCartView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalExpandingViewWithDrawer.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalTotalView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalTotalView.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalGrandTotalView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalGrandTotalView.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalExpandingView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalExpandingView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalExpandingView.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalPleaseWaitView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPleaseWaitView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIView in libPayPalMEP.a(ReceiverDetailsView.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSOperation", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_AdaptivePaymentsSOAP11BindingOperation in libPayPalMEP.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSLocale", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSLocale in libPayPalMEP.a(PPStringUtil.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSLocale in libPayPalMEP.a(PPUtils.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSException", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSException in libPayPalMEP.a(PPStringUtil.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSException in libPayPalMEP.a(USAdditions.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIColor", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPal.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMEPRootViewController.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalMEPUtility.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalProgressIndicator.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalViewClass.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalCreatePINViewController.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalTabView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalErrorView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalHelpViewController.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalAmountView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalExpandableImageView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPaymentDetailsView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalShoppingCartView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalExpandingViewWithDrawer.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalTotalView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalGrandTotalView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalExpandingView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPleaseWaitView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIColor in libPayPalMEP.a(ReceiverDetailsView.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPMEPRootViewController in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMEPRootViewController.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalLoginViewController in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalLoginViewController.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalFatalErrorViewController in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalFatalErrorViewController.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalCreatePINViewController in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalCreatePINViewController.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalReviewViewController in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalReviewViewController.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalHelpViewController in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalHelpViewController.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLConnection", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSURLConnection in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileConnect.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSURLConnection in libPayPalMEP.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableSet", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSMutableSet in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalCreatePINViewController.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPal in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPal.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalPhoneUtil in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPhoneUtil.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPStringUtil in libPayPalMEP.a(PPStringUtil.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalInvoiceItem in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalInvoiceItem.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalAdvancedPayment in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalAdvancedPayment.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalContext in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalContext.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPImageUtil in libPayPalMEP.a(PPImageUtil.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalMEPUtility in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalMEPUtility.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalInvoiceData in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalInvoiceData.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPUtils in libPayPalMEP.a(PPUtils.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPReceiverPaymentDetails in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalReceiverPaymentDetails.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalPageTracking in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPageTracking.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPTransactionManager in libPayPalMEP.a(PPTransactionManager.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_WebServiceCaller in libPayPalMEP.a(PPTransactionManager.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPMobileAPIInterface in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileAPIInterface.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalPreapprovalDetails in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPreapprovalDetails.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPMobileAPIRes in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileAPIRes.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_SOAPFault in libPayPalMEP.a(USAdditions.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_USBoolean in libPayPalMEP.a(USAdditions.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalErrorObject in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalErrorObject.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_common_RequestEnvelope in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_common_FaultMessage in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_common_ResponseEnvelope in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_common_ErrorData in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_common_CurrencyType in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_common_ClientDetailsType in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_common_BaseAddress in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_common_AccountIdentifier in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_common_PhoneNumberType in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalReceiverAmounts in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalReceiverAmounts.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_DM in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_BV in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_DL in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_BU in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_DK in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_BT in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_DJ in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_BS in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_DI in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_BR in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_DH in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_BQ in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_DG in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_BP in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_DF in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_BO in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_DE in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_BN in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_DD in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_BM in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_DC in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_BL in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_DB in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_BK in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_DA in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_BJ in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CZ in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_BI in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CX in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CW in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CV in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CU in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CS in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CR in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CQ in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CP in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CN in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CO in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CM in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CL in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CJ in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CK in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_J in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CI in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CH in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CG in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CD in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CE in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CF in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CC in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CB in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_CA in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_BY in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_BZ in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_BX in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_BW in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_i_K in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPContext in libPayPalMEP.a(PPContext.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalSystemPreference in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalSystemPreference.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPMobileAuthenticateReq in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileAuthenticateReq.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPMobileInterrogationReq in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileInterrogationReq.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalAmounts in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalAmounts.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPMobileConnect in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileConnect.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalAddress in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalAddress.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_AdaptivePaymentsSOAP11BindingResponse in libPayPalMEP.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_AdaptivePaymentsSOAP11Binding_envelope in libPayPalMEP.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_AdaptivePaymentsSOAP11Binding in libPayPalMEP.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_AdaptivePayments in libPayPalMEP.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPMobileRemoveDeviceAuthReq in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileRemoveDeviceAuthReq.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPMobileCreatePINReq in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileCreatePINReq.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_USGlobals in libPayPalMEP.a(USGlobals.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalCurrencyUtil in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalCurrencyUtil.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPal.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPhoneUtil.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalLoginViewController.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PPUtils.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPageTracking.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PPTransactionManager.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileAPIInterface.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileInterrogationRes.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileAPIRes.o)
>         l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_NSString_$_USAdditions in libPayPalMEP.a(USAdditions.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(USAdditions.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_common_ErrorParameter in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalViewClass.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PPContext.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalSystemPreference.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileInterrogationReq.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_Obfuscation in libPayPalMEP.a(Obfuscation.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(Obfuscation.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileConnect.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalReviewViewController.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileRemoveDeviceAuthReq.o)
>         l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_NSString_$_ISO8601Unparsing in libPayPalMEP.a(NSDate+ISO8601Unparsing.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(NSDate+ISO8601Unparsing.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalAmountView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPaymentDetailsView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileCreatePINReq.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalCurrencyUtil.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalTotalView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalGrandTotalView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libPayPalMEP.a(ReceiverDetailsView.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIImage", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIImage in libPayPalMEP.a(PPImageUtil.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UIImage in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalProgressIndicator.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UILabel", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-UILabel in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPal.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UILabel in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalProgressIndicator.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UILabel in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalViewClass.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UILabel in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalCreatePINViewController.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UILabel in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalTabView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UILabel in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalErrorView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UILabel in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalHelpViewController.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UILabel in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalAmountView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UILabel in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPaymentDetailsView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UILabel in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalTotalView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UILabel in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalGrandTotalView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UILabel in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPleaseWaitView.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-UILabel in libPayPalMEP.a(ReceiverDetailsView.o)
>     "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIView", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalProgressIndicator in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalProgressIndicator.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalViewClass in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalViewClass.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalErrorView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalErrorView.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalAmountView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalAmountView.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalExpandableImageView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalExpandableImageView.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalTotalView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalTotalView.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalGrandTotalView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalGrandTotalView.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalExpandingView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalExpandingView.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalPleaseWaitView in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPleaseWaitView.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSCalendar", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSCalendar in libPayPalMEP.a(USAdditions.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSCalendar in libPayPalMEP.a(NSDate+ISO8601Unparsing.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSData", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSData in libPayPalMEP.a(PPImageUtil.o)
>         l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_NSData_$_MBBase64 in libPayPalMEP.a(USAdditions.o)
>         l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_NSData_$_USAdditions in libPayPalMEP.a(USAdditions.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSData in libPayPalMEP.a(USAdditions.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSData in libPayPalMEP.a(Obfuscation.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_GZipper in libPayPalMEP.a(GZipper.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSData in libPayPalMEP.a(GZipper.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSDate", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSDate in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPal.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSDate in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalLoginViewController.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSDate in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileAPIInterface.o)
>         l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_NSDate_$_USAdditions in libPayPalMEP.a(USAdditions.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSDate in libPayPalMEP.a(USAdditions.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSDate in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSDate in libPayPalMEP.a(ap.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSDate in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileConnect.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSDate in libPayPalMEP.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>         l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_NSDate_$_ISO8601Unparsing in libPayPalMEP.a(NSDate+ISO8601Unparsing.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSDate in libPayPalMEP.a(NSDate+ISO8601Unparsing.o)
>     "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSOperation", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AdaptivePaymentsSOAP11BindingOperation in libPayPalMEP.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSNotificationCenter", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSNotificationCenter in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMEPRootViewController.o)
>     ".objc_class_name_PayPal", referenced from:
>         literal-pointer@_*OBJC@*_cls_refs@PayPal in des3AppDelegate.o
>     "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PPMEPRootViewController in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMEPRootViewController.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalLoginViewController in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalLoginViewController.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalFatalErrorViewController in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalFatalErrorViewController.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalCreatePINViewController in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalCreatePINViewController.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalReviewViewController in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalReviewViewController.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalHelpViewController in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalHelpViewController.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAutoreleasePool", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSAutoreleasePool in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPal.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSAutoreleasePool in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPageTracking.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSAutoreleasePool in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalProgressIndicator.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$*NSURL", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSURL in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPageTracking.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSURL in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileConnect.o)
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSURL in libPayPalMEP.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>     "*_objc_empty_vtable", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPal in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPal.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPal in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPal.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalPhoneUtil in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPhoneUtil.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalPhoneUtil in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPhoneUtil.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PPStringUtil in libPayPalMEP.a(PPStringUtil.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPStringUtil in libPayPalMEP.a(PPStringUtil.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PPMEPRootViewController in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMEPRootViewController.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPMEPRootViewController in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMEPRootViewController.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalInvoiceItem in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalInvoiceItem.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalInvoiceItem in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalInvoiceItem.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalAdvancedPayment in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalAdvancedPayment.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalAdvancedPayment in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalAdvancedPayment.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalContext in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalContext.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalContext in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalContext.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalLoginViewController in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalLoginViewController.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalLoginViewController in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalLoginViewController.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PPImageUtil in libPayPalMEP.a(PPImageUtil.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPImageUtil in libPayPalMEP.a(PPImageUtil.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalMEPUtility in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalMEPUtility.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalMEPUtility in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalMEPUtility.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalInvoiceData in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalInvoiceData.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalInvoiceData in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalInvoiceData.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PPUtils in libPayPalMEP.a(PPUtils.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPUtils in libPayPalMEP.a(PPUtils.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PPReceiverPaymentDetails in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalReceiverPaymentDetails.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPReceiverPaymentDetails in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalReceiverPaymentDetails.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalPageTracking in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPageTracking.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalPageTracking in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPageTracking.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PPTransactionManager in libPayPalMEP.a(PPTransactionManager.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPTransactionManager in libPayPalMEP.a(PPTransactionManager.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_WebServiceCaller in libPayPalMEP.a(PPTransactionManager.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_WebServiceCaller in libPayPalMEP.a(PPTransactionManager.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PPMobileAPIInterface in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileAPIInterface.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPMobileAPIInterface in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileAPIInterface.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PPMobileInterrogationRes in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileInterrogationRes.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPMobileInterrogationRes in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileInterrogationRes.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalPreapprovalDetails in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPreapprovalDetails.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalPreapprovalDetails in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalPreapprovalDetails.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PPMobileAPIRes in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileAPIRes.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PPMobileAPIRes in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileAPIRes.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SOAPFault in libPayPalMEP.a(USAdditions.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_SOAPFault in libPayPalMEP.a(USAdditions.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_USBoolean in libPayPalMEP.a(USAdditions.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_USBoolean in libPayPalMEP.a(USAdditions.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalErrorObject in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalErrorObject.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalErrorObject in libPayPalMEP.a(PayPalErrorObject.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_common_RequestEnvelope in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_common_RequestEnvelope in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_common_FaultMessage in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_common_FaultMessage in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_common_ResponseEnvelope in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_common_ResponseEnvelope in libPayPalMEP.a(common.o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link to libxml2 when building your app.  They should mention that in the documentation, I'm sure it's caused loads of people this problem.

Right-click on your target, select `Get Info`, go to the `General` tab, and add libxml2.dylib to your linked libraries.

Comment: Hi Jim,Thanks for that it got me down to 64 errors - I have taken a closer look at the demo code and noticed that there were some other linked libraries (including libxml2) so I went through and added those (security, addressbook and libz) but I'm still left with 64. Can you recommend anything else I should look at please? Thanks again

Comment: Oh yeah, whoops! that would help - have added and edit to question

Comment: I got same problem but I had libxml2 library included already. But I noticed from SimobBarker answer and I added Security.framework and It's worked. Great Help Dude. I spend one whole day to check build setting :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by installing to the latest SDK (I was on 3.2 or something, now on 4.2) and all is up an running - it still wouldn't have worked without adding the library Jim told me to though so I've put his down as the accepted answer

Cheers

Simon